# loading data from a datastore backup into big query throws invalid field name error

Tags: google-bigquery

When loading data from a datastore backup into big query I get the following error

Errors:
Invalid field name "hq-country". Fields must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores, start with a letter or underscore, and be at most 128 characters long.

What the work around for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to the error message, as it already lists the allowed letters.

And the hyphen (‐) punctuation mark is not among the listed valid letters. Hyphens are a big problem because if you end up mapping a column name to a variable, most languages do not like to have hyphens inside variable names, as it mostly stands for `minus/deduction`.

Rename the field, to contain only letters, numbers, and underscores, start with a letter or underscore, and be at most 128 characters long.

You can use for example: `hq_country`, or if you have multiple `hq` fields, than you can create a schema that has `hq` as a [RECORD](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/preparing-data-for-bigquery#datatypes) with multiple properties and then it would be `hq.country`