# Invalid field name "Name ". Fields must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores, start with a letter or underscore, and be at most 128 char

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to import a backup of a Firebase Real-Time Database from Google Cloud Storage into BigQuery and getting the following error:

> Invalid field name "Name ". Fields must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores, start with a letter or underscore, and be at most 128 characters long. Table: tabletest

I have tried a **second dataset** that returns the following **error**:

> Invalid field name "-Kq4_0dsRwKfOGGxGoQv". Fields must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores, start with a letter or underscore, and be at most 128 characters long. Table: tabletest

This is the **second dataset**:

```
{"users":{"someUserID_abc":{"tests":{"-Kq4_0dsRwKfOGGxGoQv":"07/02/2019 19:44:22","-Kq4_vUQTQ3b6gqMkfRL":"07/02/2019 19:48:20","-Kq4a84n9WMu3NGiE4qW":"07/02/2019 19:53:36"}}}}
```

In my initial (very large) dataset, there are lots of unique firebase keys that were [uniquely generated by firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#getting-the-unique-key-generated-by-push) and usually start with "-" (which seems to create the error with BigQuery).

My settings on the **Create table** screen are:

```
Source
Create table from: Google Cloud Storage
Select file from GCS bucket: myproject-backups/2019-07-03T02:23:34Z_myproject_data.json.gz
File format: JSON (Newline delimited)

Destination
Project name: myproject
Dataset name: database
Table type: Native table
Table name: tabletest


Schema
Auto detect
(checked) Schema and input parameters
enter code here
```

After I click the "Create table" button on the "Create table" screen, I get the error above.

I have tried different dataset and table names, adjusted the table type,  looked through each of the following for answers without any luck:

- https://github.com/metabase/metabase/issues/4087
- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas
- https://github.com/bxparks/bigquery-schema-generator/issues/14
- https://github.com/metabase/metabase/pull/4707
- https://github.com/metabase/metabase/issues/3997
- [loading data from a datastore backup into big query throws invalid field name error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28711922/loading-data-from-a-datastore-backup-into-big-query-throws-invalid-field-name-er?rq=1)

Based on [here](https://github.com/metabase/metabase/issues/4087), I am guessing the error is that "`Name`" has a space in it (and might be from the database?) and I have lots of random keys generated by firebase (which start with a leading "-").  It's a very large dataset, so I can't even unzip and open the initial gzip file without the program freezing (even plain text editor).

**EDIT:**
I created the following script to gunzip, "clean" the data for all keys in the .gzip, and re-gzip the file:

```
# remove spaces, replace leading dashmarks (replace - with the word 'dashmark'), add an underscore before numbers
file=$"myfile.json.gz"
gunzip "$file"
sed -e "s/Name /Name/g" -e "s/-/dashmark/g" -e "s/{\"\([0-9]+\)/{\"_\1/g" -e "s/,\"\([0-9]+\)/,\"_\1/g" -e "s/,\"\"/\,\"_\"/g" -e "s/{\"\"/\{\"_\"/g" < "${file%.gz}" | gzip -c > "${file%.gz}.gz"
```

This seems to eliminate the "Invalid field name..." errors, but introduces the following error:

> Error while reading data, error message: Failed to parse JSON:
>   Unexpected token; Could not parse value; Could not parse value; Could
>   not parse value; Could not parse value; Could not parse value; Could
>   not parse value; Could not parse value; Could not parse value; Could
>   not parse value; Could not parse value; Could not parse value; Could
>   not parse value; Parser terminated before end of string

[image: Screenshot of error]

I am admittedly new to `sed` statements, so perhaps I typo'd or miswrote script in a way that caused an invalid JSON object to be created in my attempt?

**Does anyone know how to remove spaces/special characters from all keys in the .gzip (or any other way to resolve this error to import the Firebase RTD .gzip into BigQuery)?**

Comment: Please include a sample test data in your json file.

Comment: @Christopher I have updated the question to include sample test data with the corresponding error

Comment: Field name `"-Kq4_0dsRwKfOGGxGoQv"` starts with minus (-) or not?

Comment: @i486 yes, it starts with a minus (-).  It is a unique key that was generated by firebase https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#getting-the-unique-key-generated-by-push.  I am fairly confident the minus (-) is the issue, but am not sure how to resolve it (possibly remove it/replace it, but easier said than done).  Almost all (if not all) unique keys generated by firebase start with this minus (-), so my initial (very large) database has lots of these and is too large to open on my computer.

Comment: I tried to load your second dataset and yes it failed with the same error and removing the '-' resolves the issue https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GiMl.png. You may need to decompress/edit/recompress the gz file --> https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/85318-find-replace-gz-file.html. Consider this as well --> https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/bigquery-export

Comment: @Christopher thanks for the suggestions. The Firebase + BigQuery integration, but I will tried writing a script and it may be a step in the right direction. I have updated the question with my new best attempt to solve the issue

Comment: The new error may be because of the timestamp format (BQ expecting format YYYY-MM-DD... while you supplied MM-DD...), check the BQ job details. I encountered this using your second dataset after removing the "-" in the field name

Comment: @Christopher This appears to be a different error.  When I check the BQ job details, it doesn't mention the timestamp issue like the BQ job details of the second dataset.  I have added a photo of the BQ job details to the question.

Comment: Also, just noticed a typo from above:  The Firebase + BigQuery integration doesn't include the database, unfortunately,* (which has led us to the script approach)

Answer (score 1):

If you copied the error message exactly, it appears that there is a space or some other whitespace character in the string "Name ".  That whitespace character is invalid, as the error message is telling you.  You'll have to dig through your data to figure out where exactly that invalid character is coming from.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I have a very large dataset that could not reasonably be manually dug through to remove each space (or as I’m coming to find, leading “-“ for every random firebase key generated). Is there a way to programmatically or systematically clean the data (replace the spaces & leading “-“) in the large .gzip file so that it will correctly import to BigQuery?

Comment: Maybe, but I don't know what it is.  All I can tell you is how I interpret that error message.

Comment: Bummer.  If there's not already a way, I would imagine it would be helpful for anyone that wants to use get insights from their Firebase Database (and wants to keep it in the Google family with BigQuery).  Not sure if you're able to pass the ask along to the appropriate party over there! :)

Comment: is there any plan to add the real-time database to Firebase's integrations here (https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/bigquery-export)?

Answer (score 0):

This error can also be printed when you run

`bq mk --table --schema xyz.json`

And the JSON file is not present in the folder from which you ran the command.

> BigQuery error in mk operation: Invalid field name "xyz.json". Fields must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores, start with
> a letter or underscore, and be at most 300 characters long.

It's file not found but the error makes you think there's a problem in your schema JSON.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the .gitignore file had excluded json files so the bq mk command was unable to find the file